# QSet::find() iterator dereferencing gets “cannot convert ‘this’ pointer” error?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, iterator

I get the error on trying to access the iterator reference:

```
QSet<UniqueWord>::iterator iter = uniqueWords.find(word);
iter->addOccurrence(position); // this gets an error
```

The error I get:

> error: C2662: ‘UniqueWord::addOccurrence’ : cannot convert ‘this’
>   pointer from ‘const UniqueWord’ to ‘UniqueWord &’ Conversion loses
>   qualifiers

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing that the iterator's `operator->` returns a `const UniqueWord *`, so you're trying to call `addOccurrence` on a `UniqueWord` that is `const`.

See the documentation here:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qset-iterator.html

Comment: So how can I possibly search for a value in the set and access that value?

Comment: You can search for it and access it as you're doing - you just can't modify it.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz - but if I want to find and modify it?

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Is there a solution to what ddriver is trying to acheive?

Comment: The reason you can't modify it is that it may affect lookup in the set if you change the `UniqueCode` in a way that causes its hash code to change. If you want to change it in a way that you know doesn't affect its hash code, you could make `addOccurrence` a `const` member function and make the non-key state mutable so that you can still change it. Alternatively, remove the element you find from the set and re-add a modified version of it.

Comment: @Spundun: Yes, but typing takes time :)

Comment: Another option is to use a map, e.g. a `QMap` - that way, you can separate out the non-key part of your `UniqueWord` from the key part.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz - thanks, you are golden. Indeed UniqueWord has a QString and a QList<uint> and only the QString is used to compute the qHash. Setting the addOccurence to const and the QList to mutable fixed it. A well deserve accept for you :)

Comment: Then why the hell is there a `find()` member function here in [QSet documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qset.html#find-1) that returns non-const Qset::iterator? How are we ever supposed to access that?!